# Unwrapping Generics?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have 3 cells. One is a TextField cell, one is a Date cell, and one is an Integer cell.

I'm using a delegate protocol to send back chosen values from each cell to the viewcontroller. Instead of writing a different protocol for each cell I would like to use the same one with a generic parameter.

Here is my code...

```
protocol MyDelegate: AnyObject {
    func passBackValue<T>(value: T)
}

class ViewController: MyDelegate {
    func passBackValue<T>(value: T) {
        if let value = value as? String {
            print("String:", value)
        } else if let value = value as? Int {
            print("Int:", value)
        } else if let value = value as? Date {
            print("Date:", value)
        } else {
            print("Wrong type")
        }
    }
}
```

My question is... is this the right approach? Should I be unwrapping the generics like above? I also found I can use the "is" keyword.

```
    if value is String {
        print("is String")
    } else if value is Int {
        print("is Int")
    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right but I need to find out what type the value is so I can handle it appropriately.

Comment: That is not what generics are designed for. If you need casting to a specific type, generics is not what you are looking for. You should only declare a function generic when the implementation of the function is the same regardless of the exact type passed into it.

Comment: An enum with associated values would be a better solution.

Comment: This protocol is badly designed. It indicates that MyDelegate must accept a `passBackValue` of literally any type at all (a CBPeripheral, a UIApplication, some random internal type you've never heard of; *anything* can be `T` here). But clearly from your code example, ViewController does not actually accept every possible type. This strongly suggests you should redesign how this callback works so  that the type that is passed is an expected type. With a callback like this, you're going to run into lots of these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 4):

An underestimated way is method overloading.

Although it requires a bit more code it's much more efficient because the compiler chooses always the right method without any type checking at runtime.

```
protocol MyDelegate: AnyObject {
    func passBackValue<T>(value: T)
}

class ViewController : MyDelegate {
    func passBackValue<T>(value: T) {
        print("Wrong type")
    }
    
    func passBackValue(value: String) {
        print("String:", value)
    }
    
    func passBackValue(value: Int) {
        print("Int:", value)
    }

    func passBackValue(value: Date) {
        print("Date:", value)
    }
}
```